# Integration of Teradata code review with Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, teradata

I have a task to configure teradata code review with Jenkins CI tool. I dont know much about teradata. So, please suggest if anyone have ever configure these two or anyone have some knowledge about integration.

Thanks in advance.